# IE8 background image doesn't show on hover

Tags: internet-explorer-8, hover, background-image

I have links that are supposed to show a background PNG (an underline) on hover. I don't want to use CSS to 'text-decoration:underline' it, as I want the underline narrower than the link itself.

This is working in FF, Chrome, Safari and IE 6 & 7. In IE 8 (and 9 I assume) it doesn't show... UNLESS I change the image's position to right under the link text (12px for the Y position in CSS, when it should be 15px to move it away from the text a bit).

Here's link: http://og.ogwebdev.com/test/nav.html

Comment: Maybe IE8 doesn't handle the invalid XHTML that well? http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fog.ogwebdev.com%2Ftest%2Fnav.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: Didn't matter but thanks for the validator reminder... moved the js to an external file so the greater than symbol didn't get snagged.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this css code:

```
#mainnav.home li a.about:hover { background:url('white-underline-about.gif') no-repeat; background-position:bottom center; }
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work... I ended up added display:inline-block to get it to work in IE8